# Web CMS vs API vs Framework - HELP?! :(

Tags: api, frameworks, content-management-system

I posed this question to my lecturer, but I would also like a variety of answers in order to better understand this conundrum of mine.  Here is the original message with names omitted.

---

Hi ******,

Thank you for your intro lecture today, I look forward to the work involved in the coming weeks.

I am however, rather confused regarding the terms CMS, API and Framework.  The internet isn't providing much help either because these terms get thrown a lot and often for the very same thing!

A have a bit of background in LAMP web development, and I will provide a hypothetical scenario, where hopefully you can tell me where these terms would fit in.

- I am using LAMP (Linux web server with Apache, MySQL and PHP).
- I am developing a website whereby the public can watch movies (umm... ignore the legal issues, purely hypothetical and for educational purposes of course!)
- I create my MySQL database using phpMyAdmin, and tables will involve 'users', 'categories', 'content' etc.
- I now create an 'admin control panel (CP)' which I will refer to as the back-end.  Authorised users, depending on their access levels (as determined by their account in the 'users' table) can add/edit/delete various things.  These changes are reflected on what I call the front-end.
- The front-end is the public facing website, whereby the public visit this website to watch films of their choice.
- The back-end (i.e. the Admin CP) controls/regulates the content of users and pretty much everything.  Over time, the developers could add more features to this for more functionality.  E.g. a comments.  Alternatively, a developer could use the Facebook comments API to include into every 'film' page on the front-end, this makes it a lot easier.

---

Now back to the main question at hand, is this a web CMS? Where would an API fit into this? Is this a framework?

Note: I'm not using anything like WordPress or Joomla etc., it's all custom coded by myself.  Using PHP and HTML5, CSS3, maybe a bit of jQuery too, and of course SQL statements via PHP to interact with the MySQL database.

I appreciate your help in this confusion of mine.

Thanks,

---

EDIT: I have commented my thoughts based on Justin's input.  If I'm on the right track let me know, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the post.

The three terms you have stated are used quite often around the web, and they are always changing. First you have a CMS, CMS stands for Content Management System, like above you have stated Wordpress and Joomla. That is where someone has already created the software to create a site/blog without having to mess with PHP, MySQL, and Apache. You are merely doing anything on the front-end, just simply posting your content, and making it live. The software does all of the back-end work for you.

API, simply put. Open-source "plug-in" which allows the user to integrate a service or application into their site or application for use.

Framework, Like Bootstrap, created by Twitter. A Web Framework is an easy way to develop a site on the front-end. It gives the learning amateur a chance at developing the front-end while learning great concepts along the way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Justin, I have heard Joomla referred to as a  'Web Framework' and a 'CMS'... ugh, see my frustration?! Well in my example, I HAVE messed with PHP/MySQL and Apache, so are you saying that what I made is NOT a CMS? Because to me, I can manage content, thus by definition is it not a CMS?

Comment: For the database, I merely create the tables (using my example), then I create the 'back-end' and use PHP to control what goes in and out of the database, there's no DIRECT contact with the database (unless I really need to, e.g. delete some column that I mistakenly added).  In the front end, I merely connect to the database, and echo all relevant film content or categories etc., these change depending on what changes in the database (which is managed through the back-end).

Comment: Sorry if I'm babbling.

Ok, so for the API, are you saying that if I made some piece of code, and gave it to other people, so that they can put it on their website, and this function allows them to view e.g. recently released film titles.  Is this an API? Because they integrate it into their own website, but actually it pulls info from my 'CMS' and displays it on their website.

Comment: No no, I don't mean that. A CMS provides many tools and contains a lot of features that helps users to house their content. So in a way, you could call your application a CMS. And for your API example your are going on the right track, but its not really simple to explain an API. For example the Google Maps API, allows developers to integrate Google Maps into their application, like a Flight Simulator or your personal iPhone application.

Comment: Alright then, so I could call my website a CMS, and then Facebook comments API is on the right track.  Using another example, I could create a 'Contact' on the front-end, and have a 'Manage Contact' page on the back-end Admin CP where authorised users can edit/add/delete contact details.  In addition, I could integrate/embed code using what Google provides on my contact page, - this would allow users to navigate the Google Maps app on the contact page? That's an example of how an API fits into what I call my website CMS?

Well then, where does 'Framework' come into all of this?

Comment: I have an idea, correct me if I'm wrong.

A framework would come into this, if I provided some sort of 'installation' of my custom made CMS to other people, they download it, upload and execute the necessary files on their web hosting server (much like how you setup vBulletin forum) - would this then mean that my CMS is now also a web Framework? Noting that users that download and use it, can edit the code themselves to suit their own needs.